# How to solve locking table caused by multi-thread reading in read-only mode of Sqlite database? because my Datebase Data will not be written

Tags: sqlite

How to solve locking table caused by multi-thread reading in read-only mode of Sqlite database?

I want to read data only.. the sqlite db  dose not  lock.

how  can i do ? because  my Datebase Data will not be written.

```
var ReadConnectionString = @"Data Source=D:\Tmp\SqlSugar\Sqlite\SqlSugar5xTest001.sqlite;Version=3;Read Only=True;";
```

```
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
SQLite error (5): database is locked in "SELECT * FROM "TestLong" WHERE Id = 8888"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//(So the query you proposed will be the most efficient:)
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTbl WHERE u_tag="tag");

// (If you were nervous about portability, you could add a limit. I suspect most DBs will offer you the same short circuit however.)
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTbl WHERE u_tag="tag" LIMIT 1);